# TeamCity 9.x Setting up an External Database with unnamed(NULL) MSSQL instance

Tags: database-connection, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm evaluating TeamCity 9.0.4 and using HSQLDB.
Now trying to setup MS SQL Server 2014 as External Database.I don't have a named instance(NULL).

So I tried the following connection URL

```
connectionUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:1433;databaseName=<database name>
connectionProperties.user=<user>
connectionProperties.password=<password>
```

When I trying to load the build server I'm getting this message.

> **TeamCity is starting**
>
> Continuing attempts to connect to the database
>
> TeamCity server is connecting to MSSQL database. The database server
>   is not started yet, or the connection properties are not properly set.

And also I checked the log file, this is what I got.

> [2015-05-20 14:08:34,513]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP -
>   Current stage: Continuing attempts to connect to the database

SQLSERVER is up,I think there is a problem with connection URL.
What can I do to solve this.

[TeamCity 9.x Documentation Setting up an External Database](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Setting+up+an+External+Database#SettingupanExternalDatabase-MicrosoftSQLServer)

Comment: Have you set the SQL JDBC Drivers? Ensure that you can resolve the SQL Server from TC, there's no firewall in the way and it's setup for Mixed Mode Authentication. This should be reasonably straight forward.

Comment: Yes, I copied the MS sqljdbc to <TeamCity Data Directory>/lib/jdbc and I have Mixed Mode Authentication.I'm using sa and have created sa TeamCity user with Admin privileges.In TeamCity 9.x Documentation they haven't given connection URL for unnamed instance so I'm worried it's not possible.

Comment: It's definitely possible as I've just done a migration from HSQLDB => Sql Server and the hostname of the Sql Server works just fine. Can you prove that you can connect to the Sql Server using the credentials from that machine. Try copying SQLCMD to the machine and connect to it via the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks DevOps.

My mistake, I was testing TeamCity locally.
Problem was with the **SQL Server Network Connection**.
TCP/IP was disabled for SQLEXPRESS

**Enable TCP/IP for SQLEXPRESS**

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Go to Protocols for SQLEXPRESS under SQL Server Network
   Configuration.
3. Right-click on TCP/IP and choose Properties. Set Enabled = YES.
4. Better check this too, click on IP Addresses tab and find the section
       IP All. Set TCP Port to 1433.